# Difference Between Column and ResultColumn Using Petapoco?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, orm, petapoco

I have Class like

```
 public class Myclass
    {
        [Column]
        public string no{ get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Address{ get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime DOB{ get; set; }
    }
```

and my select query is

```
List<Myclass> list=DAL.db.Fetch("select b.ref_no no,a.name,a.Address,a.DOB from tbla a join tblb b on b.id=a.ref_id");
```

Sometimes I get the wrong result that is I got the same record.I guess my class decoration changed to like this,

```
 public class Myclass
    {
        [ResultColumn]
        public string no{ get; set; }
        [ResultColumn]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        [ResultColumn]
        public string Address{ get; set; }
        [ResultColumn]
        public DateTime DOB{ get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column

> Is an attribute which can decorate a Poco property to mark the
>   property as a column. It may also optionally supply the DB column
>   name.

ResultColumn

> Is an attribute which can decorate a Poco property as a result only
>   column. A result only column is a column that is only populated in
>   queries and is not used for updates or inserts operations.

See here https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Mapping-Pocos

Comment: I want execute procedure and result are stored in List if i use column decoration then i will be got any problem or error?

Comment: column decoration does the same as fluent, both should work

Comment: But i have an issue i got same result after some days (apprx 5 days).that query executes over 500 times per day but after some days i got same result.if i  changed(small change [that not effect result accuracy]) in procedure that works properly for few day then problem occurs.

Comment: Any clue or suggestion please @Vadzim Dvorak